# How to make class Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-observable

I have class that has properties:

```
export class Model {
   public id: number;
   public name: string;
}
```

How to make this class observable, to listen changes inm properties.

I need something like that:

```
let m = new Model();
m.id = 10;
```

Listen changes:

```
m.pipe(map() => m.id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach here would be to inject the functionality into the constructor. I would avoid declaring subjects inside your class as they will be difficult to automatically tidy up.

You could inject subjects, but an even simpler alternative would be to inject a callback.

In the test class below, I allow for a callback per property to be injected. The relevant callback is called in the property setters if the value has changed.

```js
export class MyClass {
  private _id: number;  
  private _name: string;

  constructor(private callback?: {
    id?: () => void,
    name?: () => void
  }) {}

  get id(): number { 
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(value: number) {
    if (value === this._id) {
      return;
    }

    this._id = value;

    if (this.callback && this.callback.id) {
      this.callback.id();
    }
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    if (value === this._name) {
      return;
    }

    this._name = value;

    if (this.callback && this.callback.name) {
      this.callback.name();
    }
  }
}
```

It is then fairly simple to use this from elsewhere.

```js
myClass: MyClass = new MyClass({
  id: () => this.onIdChange()
});

ngOnInit() {
  this.myClass.id = 10;   
  this.myClass.name = 'Default' 
}

private onIdChange() {
  console.log(`id changed to ${this.myClass.id}`);
}
```

It would be simple enough to alter this to use subjects if you really want. The calling code would then be responsible for tidying up the subjects when appropriate.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hgxkc3

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kc9e4q

```
import { Component, OnInit, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
model: Model;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model.id$.subscribe(newid => {
      // do something.
    });
  }
}
export class Model {
  // @ts-ignore
  private readonly _id = new BehaviorSubject<number>();
  readonly id$ = this._id.asObservable();
  // @ts-ignore
  private readonly _name = new BehaviorSubject<string>();
  readonly name$ = this._name.asObservable();

  get id(): number {
    return this._id.getValue();
  }

  set id(val) {
    this._id.next(val);
  }

  get name(): number {
    return this._name.getValue();
  }

  set name(val) {
    this._name.next(val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add getters and setters for your class properties, add emitters inside, and then add listeners outside the class, which would listen for that emitters fired

Comment: Could you share an sample? I need to get model after changes and switchMap with httpRequest

Comment: set id(id) { this.id = id; EventEmiter.emit('idchanged', id); }

Comment: Something like that, you can extend your class from EventEmiter, and use this.emit

Comment: If you're using any framework, it also may have build in emiter functions

Comment: I use Angular how to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

```
let m = new Model();
m.id = 10;


const model$ = of(m);
model$.pipe(map()=> m.id);
```