# How to create an observable class in TypeScript using RXJS

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm struggling to figure out how to make a model observable. I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61793504/how-to-make-class-observable) and it's not what I want. I don't want individual properties to be observable, I want the entire class to be. Here's what I have so far:

```
export class ObservableModel extends Observable<any> {
    __internalSource = new BehaviorSubject(this);
    source = this.__internalSource.asObservable();
}

/**
 * Base entity class which all models should extend
 */
export class EntityModel extends ObservableModel {
   protected entityData: AnyEntity;
   protected entityState: {
      loading: boolean;
      loaded: boolean;
      reloading: boolean;
      error: boolean;
   } = {
      loading: false,
      loaded: false,
      reloading: false,
      error: false,
   };

   constructor(public type: string, public id?: string) {}

   from(value: AnyEntity) {
      const { type, id } = value;
      this.entityState = {
         loaded: true,
         loading: false,
         reloading: false,
         error: false,
      };

      this.entityData = value;
      this.__internalSource.next(this);
   }

   load() { ... }
   reload() { ... }
   private requestData() { ... }
}

export class CollectionModel extends EntityModel {
   @attr name: string;
}

export class ProductModel extends EntityModel {
   @attr name: string;
   @attr description: string;
   @hasOne('collection') collection: CollectionModel;
}
```

I have this working somewhat, but it breaks down. For instance, if I use the following in Angular

```
// component
export AppComponent {
   product = new ProductModel('product', '1');
}

// The following works...
<div *ngIf="product | async as prod">
   {{prod.loading}} works
   {{prod.reloading}} works
   {{prod.loaded}} works
   {{prod.error}} works
   {{prod.name}} works
   {{prod.id}} works
   {{prod.type}} works
</div>

// This doesn't work...
<div *ngIf="product | async as prod">
   <div *ngIf="prod.collection | async as collection">
      {{collection.loaded}} // TS throws an error that "Object is of type unknown"
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="prod.collection.loaded"> This works?
      {{ prod.collection.name }} works
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. When working with observables, you want to have immutable data and use pure functions to transform your data along the way. With a class, it's quite the opposite approach

Comment: Don't you need to use `.value` in your template to access the value and its members?

Comment: I might look into giving an Rxjs answer. But to me it sounds like you actually want something that work more like Vue's then getter/setter and now observables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the usability of it, but here's what I could come up with. The biggest issue was, as you can guess, the types. Since you use `Observable<any>` there was no way for typescript to do anything with it.

```
export class ObservableModel<T> extends Observable<T> {
    __internalSource = new BehaviorSubject(this);
    source = this.__internalSource.asObservable();
}
```

And thus now, we have to propagate that change to the entity:

```
/**
 * Base entity class which all models should extend
 */
export class EntityModel<T> extends ObservableModel<T & EntityModel<T>> {
   protected entityData: any;
   protected entityState: {
      loading: boolean;
      loaded: boolean;
      reloading: boolean;
      error: boolean;
   } = {
      loading: false,
      loaded: false,
      reloading: false,
      error: false,
   };

   constructor(public type: string, public id?: string) {
     super();
   }

   from(value: any) {
      const { type, id } = value;
      this.entityState = {
         loaded: true,
         loading: false,
         reloading: false,
         error: false,
      };

      this.entityData = value;
      this.__internalSource.next(this);
   }
   
   getState() {
     return this.entityState;
   }
}
```

Note that I've also added a getter function for the state. That's because the way you accessed data in the template was wrong (or you were thinking about using something other than `this` as the values).

Thus, now we fix how the template look like:

```
// The following works...
<div *ngIf="product | async as prod">
   {{prod.getState().loading}} works
   {{prod.getState().reloading}} works
   {{prod.getState().loaded}} works
   {{prod.getState().error}} works
   {{prod.name}} works
   {{prod.id}} works
   {{prod.type}} works
</div>

<div *ngIf="product | async as prod">
   <div *ngIf="prod.collection | async as collection">
      {{collection.getState().loaded}}
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="prod.collection | async as collection">
      <div *ngIf="collection.getState().loaded">
        {{ collection.name }} works
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Everything works just about the same, except that:

- We need to call `getState()` to have access to the "internal state"
- We need to nest the `.loaded` condition within the async pipe if we want to make it look like it's a proper stream of data

Comment: Thank you!  This makes more sense now! I also had various issues with the whole Observable<any> part. This works perfectly now.